# SQL Server date_format in join

Tags: sql-server, join, time

I have two tables with two formats date

table 1 :

```
id          time                    ref 
5           1397635972              A
10          1397635975              B
50          1397635976              C
```

table 2 :

```
id         time                   ref
10         2013/10/05              D
51         2014/01/02              E
```

how join two table     on   table1.id=table2.id   and   table1.time=table2.time

This is my attempt :

```
$sql=' select table1.id, table1.time, table1.ref, table2.id, table2.time, table2.ref 

from table1 INNER JOIN table2  

ON (table1.id = table2.id   AND  DATE_FORMAT(table1.time,'%y/%m/%d') = table2.time)';
```

Comment: What are the column types in your tables? And, what error are you getting?

Comment: No data are not shown

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select table1.id, table1.time, table1.ref, table2.id, table2.time, table2.ref 

from table1 INNER JOIN table2  

ON (table1.id = table2.id   AND  FROM_UNIXTIME(table1.time) = table2.time)
```

Are you sure that the ID needs to be a part of the join as well? This kind of join with this kind of structure would make almost no sense from a database design standpoint...

Comment: Ok, so change the SELECT to be `select table1.id, DATE_FORMAT(table1.time,'%y/%m/%d'), table1.ref, table2.id, DATE_FORMAT(table2.time,'%y/%m/%d'), table2.ref`

Answer (score 0):

**No data are not shown**

For example  FROM_UNIXTIME table2.time :

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219) :  '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
```

I need to format then become  :   2013/10/05